# I'm having a lot of trouble installing xlrd 0.9.2 for python

Tags: python, installation, xlrd

Can someone give me a guide for morons? I am somewhat out of my depth here. So far I have downloaded xlrd 0.9.2 and tried to follow the readme, but neither I nor ctrl-f can find the installer mentioned.

Comment: what os? what python? what did you try when you failed to install it? and no one has any idea what installer you are referring to at the end there

Comment: on windows 7, python 2.7.2, I would go to setup, and a python window would open and close itself. The installer is referred to in the readme, but I can't find it anywhere. Sorry about the poor question, I'm rather new to this

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/x/xlrd/xlrd-0.7.1.win32.exe#md5=801174b0a9dc60886fa3e74925b2a50d

Comment: It can't find the installation in the registry. I think it's because I'm running 64 bit, but I'm not sure. Like I said, I'm really new to this

Comment: yeah I dunno I run 32bit python even though im on a x64 ... thats a 32bit version so probably incompatible... you could install 32b python

Answer (score 19, accepted):

download

The current version of xlrd can be found here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd

extract the folder somewhere

go to the folder you extracted to ... find setup.py

open command window (start -> run-> cmd)

cd into the directory with setup.py

type: `python setup.py install`

you may need setup tools (which can be gotten here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installation-instructions)

Comment: and if in macOs and getting permission error use "sudo python setup.py install"

Answer (score 5):

If windows this should work. 
Browser to "folder with python"\scripts  Open cmd here (shift + right click and and it should be an option in the context menu.)

type inn: easy_install.exe xlrd
It should download and install if for you.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that it is really necessary for you to download the file from pypi because you have the following easy option:

```
$ pip install xlrd
```

As simple as that!
You can install it using pip, easy_install, virtualenv or even install the module manually.

The method of downloading the file(s) and installing is called manual installation.

You can do that after you have unzipped the folder and then cd to the folder and do the following:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed **pip** which is available with python installation file; then just do the following steps:

1. Open Command Line
2. Type **"pip install xlrd"**

Hope it will work